# Unable to search data using "Contains" in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a data table with two columns:

- `ID(int)`
- `DocumentData(Image)`

I am inserting `byte data`into `DocumentData` field using C# my code is below:-

```
String Query = "insert into xyz(DocumentData) values(@Document)";
SqlCommand cmdUploadDoc = new SqlCommand(Query , objC);
cmdUploadDoc.Parameters.Add("@Document", ImageBytes);
cmdUploadDoc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where I am reading the `ImageBytes` from a word file using `FileStream` code is :-

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(string filepath, FileMode.Open);
int len = (int)fs.Length;
byte[] ImageBytes= new byte[len];
fs .Read(ImageBytes, 0, len);
fs .Close();
```

but when I am fetching/searching data using `fulltext` in sql server  than this returns `null` while that keyword exists in the `DocumentData` field and file value has been successfully inserted into DB.

Query is:

```
select * 
from xyz 
where contains(DocumentData, 'Java')
```

Note: Document file which was converted into byte having some data like this

```
KEY SKILLS    Java SE 1.7, Eclipse, JUnit, Ant, Maven   
              Java EE Servlets, JSPs, Tomcat, JPA, Spring   XML Sax, DOM   
              SQL Oracle 11g   UNIX vi editor, shell scripting   UML Argo UML   
              VC Tools SVN   Certifications A+, Network+, Security+, MSP, MCSA    
FDM TRAINING
```

Comment: `'Java` ending without single quote is typing mistake?

Comment: Hassan i am using correct query by mistake i missed `'` in this question

Comment: Rahul `DocumentData` field is of Image type  not varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dump binary data into a column SQL Server has no idea what it is a representation of and will not search or index it.

You need to add a `type` column to tell the FTS system what *Filter* to use to parse the data for the catalog.

See: [Full Text Search Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142499%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I used `type` column for file extension(.doc) but result is null.

Comment: Is the data in the column actually a .doc file?

Comment: ya actually data is a .doc file. I am storing the resumes into this table.

Comment: I Got the answer this file was a doc but the data was not in doc when i changed `DOCTYPE` as `.txt` it worked fine. thanks Alex K.